# Importing data into CouchDB from MySQL

Tags: mysql, couchdb

I could query the MySQL db and export the data as JSON. Then I could import this data to Couchdb.

I'm wondering if there is a better way that I just have not heard of. For instance can Couchdb query MySQL and import the results? Perhaps someone has created a MySQL to Couchdb tool?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if such a tool has been developed for migrating from MySQL to CouchDB. However I'm curious to know the details of how you carried out the migration. I mean, exactly which queries/commands or tools did you use?

Comment: There's no way to create a tool to do this, because how to do it depends entirely on your use case. A relational database, like MySQL, and document store, like CouchDB, require entirely different approaches. This migration _cannot_ be automated.

Comment: This is not a migration for me. It's more of a one way synchronization from MySQL to Couchdb. I will be running a query on a regular schedule and importing the results to Couchdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic but I'm just learning node and couchdb. This is a start however. Parts of this came from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp).

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var nano = require('nano')('http://user:password@localhost:5984');

var db = nano.db.use('testdb');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "blah-blah.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user: "sync",
    password: "MySQLSync"
});

var sql = "SELECT * FROM testdb.mytable WHERE UPDATED > '2018-04-16 16:00:00'";

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected.");
});

con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.bulk({docs:result}, function(err, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});

con.end();
```

Comment: Yes, the code I posted was edited of course as to not include my real database address, username, and password. But the code works great. I have a where clause in my SQL statement as I am going to run this code every hour. I will only import new records from my MySQL database to couchdb. You can leave this out if you want all records say for a migration.